# How to use multiple filters in android studio with firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use multiple filters like `SELECT * table_name WHERE age=20 && country = UK && weight=60` in firebase database.

My code:

```
 private void loadListFood(String catagoryId) {
    adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>(Food.class,
            R.layout.food_item,
            FoodViewHolder.class,

            foodList.orderByChild("menuId").equalTo(catagoryId)

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(FoodViewHolder foodViewHolder, Food food, int i) {
            foodViewHolder.food_name.setText(food.getName());
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(food.getImage())
                    .into(foodViewHolder.food_image);

            final Food local=food;
            foodViewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListner() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                    //Toast.makeText(FoodList.this, ""+local.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent foodDetail = new Intent(FoodList.this,FoodDetail.class);
                    String FoodID=adapter.getRef(position).getKey().toString();
                    foodDetail.putExtra("FoodId",FoodID);
                    startActivity(foodDetail);


                }
            });

        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

So I want to **load menuID = categoryID and status==available** items into recyclerview from firebase database

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In realtime database, you cannot use `AND` query. Instead you can combine those attributes into one attribute:

```
Users
  randomId
       age :20
       country: UK
       weight : 60
       age_country_weight : 20_UK_60
```

Then you can do:

```
foodList.orderByChild("age_country_weight").equalTo("20_UK_60")
```

Answer (score 1):

`Firebase Realtime Database` does not support multiple `equalTo`. If you want continue use `Realtime Database` you will need to structure your data differently in so you can query based on one `equalTo` in combination with `orderByChild`.

But you can avoid this limitation by switching on `Firestore` which supports `Query` based on multiple `whereEqualTo` for example:

```
Query query = collectionRefference.
.whereEqualTo("menuID", "categoryID")
.whereEqualTo("status", "available");
```